# jquery will drag items but I can't re-order them

Tags: jquery

Ok so basically I have a few checkbox lists that will generate a .txt file with the selection options. What I need is for the checkboxes to be draggable and positionable. I've got it to where I can drag the boxes around but can't move their positions. This needs to be done so the output can be in a custom order.

Here's my source code, renamed from php to txt:

The main page & the formatting page:
http://buttsecs.org/mmgen/index.txt & matchmodes.txt

CSS:
http://buttsecs.org/mmgen/style.css

I've tried numerous versions of jquery and jqueryui. This script works fine on a test page, I assume it has something to do with how my checkboxes are created? Would really appreciate some help on this. Thanks!

Comment: I'd be happy to look at your code, but I'm at work and your domain name scares me. Any chance you could post a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Jayraj his links appear safe (I clicked without thinking). Can't say for the rest of the domain though. OP, can you link to your test page?

Comment: Yeah sorry about the site name, its just a joke name for some buddies I game with. I don't know how to make a jsfiddle. The test site is http://buttsecs.org/mm and the jsfiddle that i used code from is here --> http://jsfiddle.net/PtskU/

Comment: Checked out the webpage. So, to confirm, you want the checkboxes in each item to be able to move independently of the box they are in?

Comment: Yeah, it turned out that I had a tag in a wrong location. They work great now. Thanks!

Comment: @epilimic To help future users, you should answer your own question in the box below, and mark it as accepted